# React - Display new component when form is submitted

Tags: javascript, reactjs, components

Can someone tell me why the SearchResult is not displaying when the form is submitted?

```
export default class Search extends React.Component {
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = {
            search: ""
        }
        this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
        this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
    }
    handleChange(event) {
        this.setState({
            search: event.target.value
        });
      }
    handleSubmit() {
       return <SearchResult/>
    }

    render() {
        return(
        <div>
        <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
            <label>
            Name:
            <input type="text" value={this.state.search} onChange={this.handleChange} />
            </label>
            <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
        </form>
        </div>
        );
    }
}
```

I don't have any errors appearing, when I submit it, the page just reloads and stays on the Search component and not the SearchResult component.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In React, you can create distinct components that encapsulate behavior you need. Then, you can render only some of them, depending on the state of your application.

So, firstly add a new state property like:

```
this.state = { search: "", isSubmitted: false };
```

Then update `handleSubmit()` method like:

```
handleSubmit() {
   this.setState({isSubmitted: true});
}
```

Then finally update `render()` function like:

```
render() {

    const isSubmitted = this.state.isSubmitted;

    let content;
    if (isSubmitted) {
      content = <SearchResult/>;
    } else {
      content = (
        <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
            <label>
            Name:
            <input type="text" value={this.state.search} onChange={this.handleChange} />
            </label>
            <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
        </form>
      );
    }

    return <div>{content}</div>;
}
```

---

For more info:

- [Conditional Rendering In React](https://reactjs.org/docs/conditional-rendering.html)

Answer (score 2):

Your component is not re-rendering when the form is submitted and you are actually not returning the *SearchResult* in the render method itself.

I would simply add a *showResults* property to your state and if true display the results instead of the form.

Also, be sure to prevent a page reload using *event.preventDefault* in your *handleSubmit* function.

Your code would look like this:

```
export default class Search extends React.Component {
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = {
            search: "",
            showResults: false
        }
        this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
        this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
    }
    handleChange(event) {
        this.setState({
            search: event.target.value
        });
      }
    handleSubmit(e) {
       e.preventDefault()
       this.setState({...this.state, showResults: true});
    }

    render() {
        if(this.state.showResults){
            return <SearchResult />
        }
        else{
            return(
                <div>
                <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
                <label>
                    Name:
                    <input type="text" value={this.state.search} onChange=. 
                    {this.handleChange} />
                </label>
                <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
            </form>
            </div>
            );
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You could set state in `handleSubmit()` function and change `render()` function so it displays the component depending on criteria

```js
export default class Search extends React.Component {
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = {
            search: "",
            submitted: false
        }
```

```js
handleSubmit() {
  this.setState({
   submitted: true
  })
}
```

```js
render() {
  if(this.state.submitted) {
    return <SearchResult/>
  }

  return(
    <div>
    <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
   <label>
   Name:
   <input type="text" value={this.state.search} onChange={this.handleChange} />
   </label>
   <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
   </form>
  </div>
  );
    }
```